# Firefox 3.5, what motion am I making that keeps popping tabs into new windows?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I updated to Firefox 3.5, (and the 3.5.1 update) on WinXP SP3 and so far like it quite a bit.  Not much different, but seems faster and better.

One thing that is driving me nuts is that when I switch back to my main window, with three tabs open (Two mail accounts, and a page I check regularly) and I click on a tab, it pops out into a new window.

I cannot figure out what I am doing to cause it.  I think and intend to just click on the tab, which I must do thousands of times a day.  But usually when I switch back from another window this causes a pop out.

Good news is, with 3.5 it is pretty easy to drag it back, but it is really annoying, and I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing to cause it.

Anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: I have this issue occasionally on my MacBook, since the touchpad is a bit iffy after 18 months.  If you're on a laptop or have an older mouse, this could be causing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably clicking a little too slowly (between mousdown and mouseup) with a little too much velocity, initiating a "drag" operation, pulling the tab out into its own window. This happens to me sometimes with Google Chrome.

It looks like [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12276) is the only way to manipulate this behavior, for now.

Comment: You think?  But why only when I swap windows, I have yet (in my memory) triggered it once I was on the window.  Well, something to think about.  Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: This happens to me in chrome sometimes too. Never in FF though.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just tried doing that in FF a dozen times, but couldn't reproduce this higher rate of pop-out.

Comment: I was plagued with this on Google Chrome, and now its starting to happen on firefox 3.5. Something to do with the way touchpad tap-drag works has changed in ff3.5

Comment: geoffc, maybe its because of the direction you're usually moving the mouse when swapping windows.

Comment: @TPops:  Probably true.  Good point.

Comment: I will try out the Addin and see if it helps!  Thanks that was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just clicking, you might be drag-and-dropping, even slightly, the tab into the main canvas: This causes the tab to open in a new window.

So maybe you're not clicking fast enough, or some kind of event tells firefox that the mouse button is still hold when you've "un-clicked" the button. Performance Issues?

Answer (score 2):

I get this with Chrome all the time.  Even though I'm sure I'm doing a normal click, sometimes it thinks I'm dragging the tabs halfway across the screen.  This is usually associated with heavy CPU load from flash movies on the tab.